# Telerik RadWindow And AdjustResizing Problem In FireFox (Scroll Bars Appear)

Tags: resize, telerik, scrollbar, radwindow

I am so confused for setting the width and height of DIV and FIELDSET inside A RadWindow.
When I browse my radwindow in firefox with this code:

```
setTimeout(function() { GetRadWindow().autoSize(true) }, 500);
```

every thing is ok in IE 8 - but in Firefox I have scrolls bars.

How can I remove them?

My width and height of div and fieldset are like :

```
<style type="text/css"> 
html, body, form 
{ 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: #f2f2de; 
} 
fieldset 
{ 
    height: 581px; 
} 
* + html fieldset 
{ 
    height: 585px; 
    width: 840px; 
}
```

```
<div style="width: 850px; height: 600px;">
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Note : Notify Email Address Not Work For Me!
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i asked about this issue from telerik team and they told me in new versions this problem is solved.plz look at my Question Date And This Answer Date...
i think this problem has been solved in newer versions / however this problem has nothing to do with Doctype...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using XHTML - compliant Doctype in your content page - this should help.

Comment: thanks for your answer / there is no content page and my DocType is :
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

...